# C# Mask or Hide or Remove or Redact certain areas in pdf file

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-manipulation

Currently we have a webservice called by clients to **get a pdf file**. The webservice goes out to another system to fetch that file, returned in **hex format**. Our webservice then converts the Hex string to bytes and then responds back to the clients with the pdf file, as below:

```
Byte[] pdfBtyes = ConvertHexStringToBytes(hexValueFromOtherSystem);

HttpResponse _response = Context.Response;
_response.Clear();
_response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
_response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + FileName + ".pdf");
_response.BufferOutput = true;
_response.AddHeader("Content-Length", pdfBtyes.Length.ToString());
_response.BinaryWrite(pdfBtyes);
_response.End();
```

BUT NOW we need to find a way **to mask or hide or redact or totally remove some content** from the file, basically some sensitive information based on user type, before sending it in response to clients. 
And this **has to be in real-time**, like before when we had no masking requirement.

The hiding / masking / removing / redacting, for now is assumed to be **based on a specific positional area** of the file. Like identify a Left-Top, Right-Top, Right-Bottom, Left-Bottom **rectangular region**. 
Another thing is, there could be more than 1 such rectangular regions.

Or if PDFs have any concept of a **Line Numbers**, we could use that if feasible, like mask Line# 5,6,7,8,9 of the file, from Left-0 to Right-n.

**Q1** - The core question is how this could be achievable using any open source & free libraries, APIs, SDKs? Or Custom development from scratch? 
Or must go for a paid option like PDFTron (which seems like only meant for windows applications) https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples/cs/PDFRedactTest?platforms=dotnet.

OR SyncFusion
https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/easy-ways-to-redact-pdfs-using-c.aspx

**Q2** - The second & in fact more crucial question on my mind is, is it even a good idea to do this in real-time? Can it be done in a time frame like within 500 ms?

Comment: *"Can it be done in a time frame like within 500 ms?"* - on one hand that depends on your server resources and the number of requests processed in parallel. On the other hand obviously the complexity if the pdfs matters.